# Bug? ListBoxGroupHeader and Frame = Class Not Found

Tags: listbox, frame, firemonkey

IDE 10.4.1

I am interested in the effect, when scrolling through the list, the current header remains visible as the first element of the list.

This works great, with the property set to Plain.

But if you throw your own Frame on the ListBoxGroupHeader. Then on scrolling, when it creates the anchored object at the top, it cannot find my Frame class.

And acc. does not create a frame and the anchored object is empty.

Stack:

```
procedure TCustomListBox.UpdateStickyHeader;

function TFmxObject.Clone(const AOwner: TComponent): TFmxObject;

function TReader.ReadRootComponent(const Root: TComponent): TComponent;

procedure TComponent.ReadState(Reader: TReader);

procedure TReader.ReadData(const Instance: TComponent);

procedure TReader.ReadDataInner(const Instance: TComponent);

function TReader.ReadComponent(Component: TComponent): TComponent;

  procedure CreateComponent;

ComponentClass := FindComponentClass(CompClass);
```

http://prntscr.com/wg64n2

What can i do to fix it? Or i can't use Frame here?

Comment: this bug has a long history. http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.firemonkey/cloning-frames-in-firemonkey-xe/1051949

Answer (score 0):

Simle need call

RegisterClass()